# Выделение всех значений в строке таблицы HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется

```
 <table border="1">
    
        <tr align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6">
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Icon</th>
            <th>Object Name</th>
            <th>Object Type</th>
            <th>Creation Date</th>
        </tr>
      
        <c:forEach items="${objList}" var="obj">
            <tr>
                <td><label><input type="radio" name="object_id" onclick="setObjectButton(this);" value="${obj.obj_id}" /> ${obj.obj_id}</label></td>
                <td>${obj.main_type}</td>
                <td>${obj.obj_name}</td>
                <td>${obj.obj_type}</td>
                <td>${obj.creation_date}</td>
                
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">
                <table class="buttons"
                    style="width: 100%; text-align: center; border: none !important;">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit" disabled onclick="page='ObjectList'" /></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="delete" name="delete" disabled onclick="page='ObjectDelete'" /></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Create Directory" name="addDir" onclick="page='ObjectList'" /></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Create Document" name="addDoc" onclick="page='ObjectList'" /></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Access" name="access" disabled onclick="page='ObjectList'" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Как при выборе радиобаттона выбирать значения всей строки таблицы как отдельно взятые??

То есть необходимо чтобы от Radiobutton была привязка к
${obj.main_type}
${obj.obj_name}
и всем остальным значениям а не только к ${obj.obj_id}

## То есть на данный момент выбирается только значение колонки ID а нужно чтобы выбирались все значения столбцов в одной строке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: объясните подробнее как должно выглядеть то что Вы хотите увидеть в итоге, а не на примере кода.

Comment: @OlmerDale Необходимо выбрать строку а не только значение ID

Comment: @OlmerDale обновил вопрос

Comment: Вы уж меня простите, совершенно нету время. Если Вы ещё не сделали, то хочу уточнить, что значит выбирались? Подсвечивались другим цветом или данные собирались в объекте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно сделать выделение строки, то можно сделать вот так -

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');

table.addEventListener('change', table_changeHandler);

function table_changeHandler(event) {
  let tr = table.querySelector('tr[data-active="true"]');

  if (tr) {
    tr.dataset.active = false;
  }

  event.target.closest('tr').dataset.active = true;
}
```

```css
tr[data-active="true"] td {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">

  <tr align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6">
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Icon</th>
    <th>Object Name</th>
    <th>Object Type</th>
    <th>Creation Date</th>
  </tr>

  <tr data-active="false">
    <td><label><input type="radio" name="object_id" value="${obj.obj_id}" />first</label></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-active="false">
    <td><label><input type="radio" name="object_id"  value="${obj.obj_id}" />second</label></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-active="false">
    <td><label><input type="radio" name="object_id" value="${obj.obj_id}" />third</label></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7">

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Если же нужны значения, то можно вот так -

```
const table = document.querySelector('table');

table.addEventListener( 'change', table_changeHandler );

function table_changeHandler(event){
  let td = event.target.closest('tr').querySelectorAll('td');

  parseTableRow( Array.from(td) );
}

function parseTableRow(tdAll){
  console.log(tdAll); // парсим данные
}
```